# Linq, create new record id

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

using C#, i have a function called "addmember". it uses linq to create new record in the database. i simply need to help create a unique number id when each record is created. i initially used the GUID function but i just want a smaller number (ie..  1-200).

```
test_abDataConext Class = new test_abDataConext Class();
test_ab member = new test_ab();

member.memberID = GUID();
member.email = txtEmail.Text;
```

Comment: Why can you not use the database to provide the ID numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest, that you use an IDENTITY column (in case of SQL Server) or any other autogenerating mechanism to generate IDs on inserting records.

Then you can tell LINQ2SQL in the designer that your ID column has a computed value by setting the property `Auto Generated Value` to true and `Auto-Sync` to Always or OnInsert.

Comment: No codebehind. in the LINQ2SQL designer add the MemberID property or change type of it to Int and set the properties as described in my answer. The rest is done by LINQ2SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Identity would be cleanest as @jan suggests because it controls the ordering for you.  Otherwise, a way to do it is query the DB for the largest ID value and add one.  Unless there is some scheme you can employ to ensure the uniqueness.